# How to integrate Google Maps into Angular 9 app

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular9

I am trying to follow [this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component) tutorial to display google maps in my Angular 9 app, but I am facing the below issue.

I carried out the below steps:

1. I ran `npm install @angular/google-maps`
2. Imported the below Module & added it to my imports array in *AppModule*:

`import { GoogleMapsModule } from '@angular/google-maps';`

3. Adding this script tag with my api key:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"></script>`

4. Added this tag to my HTML:

`<google-map></google-map>`

But when I load the page I get this error in the console:

[image: console_error]

Can someone please tell me what is causing this error, & how it can be resolved? I've followed the steps in the tutorial so I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Try this https://dev.to/devpato/setup-google-map-in-angular-app-the-pro-way-3m9p

Comment: Hi, I can't prove this, but try to change to this:
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Hi @dota2pro I tried your tutorial, but the error message I'm getting on that is `google is not defined`

Comment: Load the google script and then your component after a timeout of 300 ms and see

Answer (score 2):

I found this would only work when I imported the script into the head of my index.html. Anywher below that and I get errors.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>apoms</title>
  <base href="/">

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;key=[APIKey]"></script>

  ....
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <!-- <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported import { MapInfoWindow } from '@angular/google-maps'; in your component and use @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow; in class?.